# Performa multiple operations on dataframe pandas python

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I wanted to perform following operation on dataframe ata time

```
opr1 = df[df != ''] 
opr2 = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace= True) 
opr3 = df.dropna(axis=0, how='all', inplace= True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use indexing for set `0` by mask:

```
df[df['A'] == 0] = 0
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  0  0  0  0
1  6  7  2  8
2  2  8  6  3
3  0  0  0  0
```

Alternative is use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df = df.mask(df['A'] == 0, 0)
```

If performance is important use `DataFrame` constructor and [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df['A'].to_numpy()[:, None] == 0, 0, df), 
                  index=df.index, 
                  columns=df.columns)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  0  0  0  0
1  6  7  2  8
2  2  8  6  3
3  0  0  0  0
```

Performance in sample data for 10k rows, 4 columns, 50% matched data:

```
#10k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 2500, ignore_index=True)


In [101]: %timeit df[df['A'] == 0] = 0
465 µs ± 40.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [103]: %timeit df.mask(df['A'] == 0, 0)
2.56 ms ± 419 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


In [105]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(np.where(df['A'].to_numpy()[:, None] == 0, 0, df),  index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
123 µs ± 666 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```